# C#: How do I check if a DataGrid is empty?

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which I want to check whether empty or not. Is there a way to do this? Currently, I have an idea like below code.

```
if (grdMass.DataSource=="")
{
    cmdRelease.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    cmdRelease.Enabled = true; ;
}
```

Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Is there anyone else with more question no accepted answers?  Maybe he wants to become some kind of SO legend.

Comment: Remember that the item count returned also includes the grid headers too

Answer (score 9):

To check if something is empty you can check if the Items property is empty.

```
grdMass.Items.Count == 0
```

Comment: This fails with an exception when used with DataGrid in WPF because grid's data source could be null, and you cannot and do the above also. At runtime, it throws an exception due to the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to check if the grid view is empty is by checking the number of rows it has.

```
if(gvMyData.Rows.Count == 0)
     // Empty
else
     // Not Empty
```

Hope this helps **;)**

Answer (score 2):

If nothing has been bound to the `DataGrid` the `DataSource` property will be `null`:

```
cmdRelease.Enabled = (grdMass.DataSource != null);
```

Comment: Not that you'd intentionally do this, but if you set the datasource, but then didn't call databind, there would be nothing on the screen, and yet for this request, this assertion would be true, when it probably shouldn't be.